# Offline JPEG metadata editor

Tags: image-processing, metadata-editor, jpg

I use Google Picasa (the desktop program for Windows) for managing my JPEG images collection. I edit image descriptions and geolocation of JPEG images. It saves this metadata into the image file itself, not in some external file or database. And it is offline.

It is a brilliant program (noting that it also has excellent facial recognition). Sadly Google has retired it so I am seeking a substitute as problems with Picasa begin to mount.

Requirements:

- Desktop, offline program
- Metadata stored in image file itself
- Can edit geolocation, description

Comment: Also for Windows? Do you have a budget, or does it have to be gratis?

Comment: @unor: Software license does not matter in this case, although a competitive freeware program is always to be preferred.